# Golang: get the full url from an https call

Tags: go, https, proxy

I made a proxy using http.NewRequest here is the code in short:

```
     main(){
        ...        
        // struct to initialise the proxy params
        P = NewProxy(..)
        http.ListenAndServe(":9999", P)
        ... 
    }
```

;

```
   func (p Proxy) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ...
            req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", r.URL.String(), nil)
        ...
    }
```

I need to get the full URL to make the call, for the http it works but for the https i got  **www.example.com:443**

**Edited**

I want to create a proxy who can use socks5(using tor) and classic proxies then my scraper(casperjs) can make request through it.
Firstly i stared with tcp proxy using:

```
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", p.from)

connection, err := listener.Accept()

remote, err := net.Dial("tcp", p.to)
```

and `io.Copy(to, from)` to copy the data from the client to the remote server and vice-versa my code was heavily inspired by [this gist by vmihailenco](https://gist.github.com/vmihailenco/1380352)

it works fine for both http and https because the listening was in the TCP couche BUT the problem with this method i can't use **socks5** and **http(s)** i have to set the type of the proxy in the call

```
$casperjs --proxy=127.0.0.1:9999 --proxy-type=socks5 bbuy.js
```

but what i need is that my proxy can concurrently send several requests, each using a different proxy.
and to do that i have to modifay the transport for each request

```
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://proxyIp:proxyPort")
http.DefaultTransport = &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}
```

thats why i choose to use the http.NewRequest and to do it i have to get the full url then i can make the call 
the problem now as i said before when my scraper try to scrape for example **https://example.com?a=1&b=2** the resulte that i got using  `r.URL.String()`
is **example.com:443** but if it's a `http` web site i got the full url

any suggestion or idea to solve this problem

Comment: You can't serve HTTP and HTTP from the same port

Comment: HTTPS on the HTTP port (80) without TLS = HTTP.
What do you want exactly ?

Comment: What was it you got from r.URL.String() vs what were you expecting?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Instead of using `r.URL.String()` you can concatenate different url component and get ride of the `port`? (with `net.SplitHostPort()`)

Comment: nop, it doesnt work,cna't get the different part of the url